# WIndows SessionInit taking way too long on cold boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, ssd

I'm experiencing issues with my laptop.

Config :

- Dell Latitude E6430
- Intel i7-3630QM
- 8GB RAM
- 256Go Kingston SSDNOW V300 SSD

Pretty much all informations we need here

Since I upgraded to Windows 10, I'm experiencing a very long cold boot time (when I use Restart, fast startup being enabled, the problem doesn't occur)

Here are the graphs I extracted from the trace :

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

[image: Graph 3]

The trace can be found here :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9VrV6g_CA8_VGppLTk2WWJybFk

I tried to format and reinstall, the problem comes back after a few minutes (while installing drivers). I haven't yet found which one. I will resume my investigations when I get back from work but in the meantime I ask to you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the generic events tab in the `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP` provider data, you see that starting the device with the hardware ID of `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E3A&SUBSYS_05341028&REV_04\3&11583659&0&B0` takes 30s to start:

[image]

The Id belongs to `Intel(R) Management Engine Interface`

[image]

which is only a enterprise feature and normal home users can disable this device in device manager.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks. That was my first trace, I will re-open the file and try to find what you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: ok, click on the green button to accept he reply as answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235