# Very slow boot time on Windows 10. 100+ second long Session Init boot phase

Tags: windows-10, boot

Ever since I did a clean install of windows 10 about two years back my computer has been very slow to boot on an SSD. I recently took a WPR of it and discovered the Session Init phase is taking 100+ seconds to complete.

Here is an image of the WPA screen, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkLpg.jpg, here are my system specs, https://i.stack.imgur.com/huUYo.jpg, and here is a pastebin of my following steps in [Newish Windows 10 installation taking ~ 20 minutes in the pre session init phase](https://superuser.com/questions/1205024/newish-windows-10-installation-taking-20-minutes-in-the-pre-session-init-phase,https://pastebin.com/Jc9TMZng).

The only thing that I have gathered from looking at it is that it has something to do with Smss.exe but I'm not familiar enough with WPR to be able to deduce anything else.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: REMOVETHIShttps://www.dropbox.com/s/eey6hxhagh4url6/normal.Boot_1.7z?dl=0 here is the zipped ETL file for closer inspection

Comment: share the zipped ETL file if you need help

Comment: ok, I posted an answr and it looks like the Intel Management Engine Interface causes the elay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the [same issue like the user here](https://superuser.com/a/1149757/174557), where the `Intel(R) Management Engine Interface` which corresponds to the hardware ID `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_8CBA&SUBSYS_85341043&REV_00\3&11583659&0&B0` (`\Driver\MEIx64 - MEIx64.sys`) causes the delay

[image]

Disable this device in device manager, you don't need this in normal home usage.

Comment: This immediately fixed the issue, what is the intel management engine used for anyway?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/is-the-intel-management-engine-a-backdoor/ ignore it and always disable it