# Slow boot - caused by smss

Tags: windows, boot, performance

There is delay about 1.5 min. during boot, I can't diagnose it.

"Boot Degradation" custom log:
[image: "Boot Degradation" custom log]

Delay is caused by "smss". Tried safe mode, no items in autostart list, uninstalled all audio and video drivers, turned off/on page file etc. - no results, the same delay.

I have one more specially optimized Win10 system on this computer installed on separate drive - no problem with boot, 4-5 sec. for "blue window" screen.

UPDATE:

I made trace file with WPR: https://dropmefiles.com/nf2Az

In initial part of boot there's activity of "autochk" process:

[image: Boot with "autochk"]

I disabled process with "chkntfs /x" command, but delay is still there:

[image: Boot without "autochk"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SOLVED Boot Session\_Init taking forever Win10](https://superuser.com/questions/1246552/solved-boot-session-init-taking-forever-win10)

Comment: I made trace file with WPR:  
  
https://dropmefiles.com/nf2Az  

In initial part of boot there's activity of "autochk" process:  

<img src="https://freeimage.host/i/H3KcaKx" width="100" height="100">  

I disabled process with "chkntfs /x" command, but delay is still there:  

<img src="https://freeimage.host/i/H3Kwysp" width="100" height="100">

Comment: If `autochk` is taking a long time to run, that might indicate drive integrity issues, and it has flagged the drive as dirty. Do you have any `SMART` errors on your drives? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/autochk

Comment: All drives have "Good" health, all are clean. Tried to remove non-system disks - the same delay. And (as I wrote) currently autochk is disabled for all non-removable drives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by `Intel(R) Management Engine Interface`:

Thanks to @magicandre1981, I found his answer:

[Very slow boot time on Windows 10. 100+ second long Session Init boot phase](https://superuser.com/questions/1242529/very-slow-boot-time-on-windows-10-100-second-long-session-init-boot-phase)