# Windows 10 very long SessionInit phase

Tags: windows-10, boot, sata

I have recently upgraded my cpu (ryzen 1600 -> ryzen 3600) and added a 3tb hard drive to my PC. First couple of boots were normal, but now I am getting 10-20 minute boot times and I can't find the issue.
Config:

- AMD Ryzen 3600
- 16 GB of 2666 RAM
- Gigabyte AB350M-D3H motherboard
- gtx 1060 6 GB
- m.2 nvme SSD as boot drive (samsung 970 evo)
- 3 HDDs

I have tried finding problems in windows using sfc /scannow, DISM, CHKDSK. Automated diagnosics when rebooting 3 times in a row don't find any problems. I have an ubuntu system installed on one of the HDDs, it boots fine.

I have tried disconnecting the new HDD and also all of the HDDs, that doesn't seem to help (I didn't wait for the full boot, but waited for 5-10 minutes and it didn't boot, so I thought that was enough to say that nothing changed).

I have tried doing a boot trace and found that the SessionInit phase was very long, like in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1149664/windows-sessioninit-taking-way-too-long-on-cold-boot/1149757#1149757).

[image of timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRD4u.png)

However I didn't find any entry in Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP->DeviceStart where the delay between win:start and win:stop is long. There is only a strange skip where it seems no device was being started?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcDrx.png)

I also checked the DeviceEnum tab, and there I noticed that at around the same time as this time skip was a bunch of repeating entries that started and stopped the same 2 devices with ids

```
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7901&SUBSYS_B0021458&REV_51\4&3298272d&0&0042
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7901&SUBSYS_B0021458&REV_51\4&9b70dcb&0&0043
```

[beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qukgv.png)

[close to the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrYwj.png)

This continues until around 660 seconds.

Could you advise how to find which devices have these IDs, and what could be the problem with them?

I noticed that the first part of the id (PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7901&SUBSYS_B0021458&REV_51) is the hardware id of AMD SATA Controller in device manager. There are 2 identical AMD SATA Controllers there, could that be a problem? Can I uninstall one of them, or is this normal?

Any recommendations of where to look for other errors are welcome, I don't know how to use the Windows Performance Analyzer.

Here is the full trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DvHpTN8YrC0xGzylM96S71hVQn6ycB08/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: I have found that these ids are certainly the AMD SATA Controllers:

[image: controllers]

Comment: Disconnect the HDDs. If that solves the boot delay replace the SATA cables. If that has no effect check all drives for their S.M.A.R.T values. Most likely one drive is just dying and causing the delay as the controller re-tries to read something for a large number of times but the read is failing again and again.

Comment: @Robert I have disconnected all my drives (except the m.2 nvme SSD) and ran boot trace again, same problem, even same duration (662 seconds). I checked the SMART values, they seem to be fine. Could the SSD be dying? It's an nvme m.2 type, so I'm not sure if the SATA Controllers are responsible for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by booting into safemode and deleting both AMD SATA Controllers in device manager (with the checkmark "delete drivers"). After a reboot they are replaced by Standard SATA AHCI Controllers, and the system boots quickly, as it should.